# VBA Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi can anyone help me with this,

I am quite new to VBA so it might be an easy fix, but I keep getting the

> (Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error)

when I try to run this code. It normally will run but then says it afterwards.

```
Sub Insert_Row_PART_2()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do Until Worksheets("Ref").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value > 10000
    
    Rows(Worksheets("Ref").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlUp, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    i = i + 1
    
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

NOTE: The line giving me the error is: Rows(Worksheets("Ref").Cells(i + 1, 3).Value).Select

I am trying to insert rows on a sheet called MARA2+MARD2, while being on the sheet, based on the values in row 3 (C) in my sheet called "Ref".

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the value in `Worksheets("Ref").Cells(i + 1, 3)` when it fails?

Comment: @Warcupine The Values are positive integers, they could be anything from 1 to about 6000. The limit set at 10000 is because I made the formula finding the value needed to be set at 10000 when it is no longer needed.

Comment: But what specifically is the value when it fails? I suspect it is a blank value, which wont work in `.cells()`

Comment: @Warcupine I get the error when I get to the end of the loop, so when the value of the cell reaches the 10,000.

Comment: If the value is 10,000 then that won't stop the loop you need `>=` so it never hits a blank cell.